# Visualization profile creation using neo4j java api's

Tags: neo4j

We have a requirement in our project, where we want to create visualization profile using Neo4j java api's. I googled, but didn't get anything useful.

Is there anyway to create the style visualization profile using neo4j java api's. We are using neo4j-1.8.1.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by style visualisation profile? For what purpose? WebUI, graphviz or D3 viz?

Comment: We can create visualization profile in neo4j web ui(http://host:7474) from 'Explore and Edit Data browser' option, but it will be browser dependent.  We want to control how visualization looks using neo4j api's. We want to Create new visualization profile, like adding style rules for nodes, relationships, background color,label color,label font size, font type, showing custom icon for nodes etc.

Comment: Please suggest if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getExecutionPlanDescription` from your result to get the execution plan of your query.

```
Result result = graphDb.execute(query);
System.out.println(result.getExecutionPlanDescription());
```